# pointer issues in C structs

Tags: c, pointers

I had a question on c pointers. I'm currently building my own shell.  I have a memory leak to do with pointers according to valgrind. I've tried many different ways to free the memory all which usually end up with segfaults. My code is pretty complecated so I'm not going to post it. But essentially one part of the code I have is:

```
void seperateCommands(char *input[]){
   process *processArr[10];
   char **currInstruction;
   currInstruction = calloc(300 , sizeof(char *));
   if(input[inputIndex] == NULL){
   currInstruction[instructionIndex] = NULL;
  //printString(currInstruction);
    process *tempP;
    tempP = (process *)calloc(1,sizeof(process));
    tempP->instruction = currInstruction;
    processArr[processIndex] = tempP;
    processIndex++;
     break;
    }
    }
    job *j;
    j = (job *) calloc(1,sizeof(job));
    j->currProcess = processArr[0];
```

And the free method :

```
 void free_job(job* j){
      int i = 0;
      if(j->currProcess != NULL){
        free(j->currProcess->instruction);
      }
      if(j->currProcess != NULL){
        free(j->currProcess);
      }
      if(j->twoProcess){
        if(j->secondProcess != NULL){
          free(j->secondProcess->instruction);
          free(j->secondProcess);
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < 300; i++){
        free(j->instruction[i]);
      } 
      free(j->instruction);
      free(j);
    }
```

And two structs:

```
typedef struct job{
    char **instruction;
    struct job* nextJob; //next active
    pid_t pgid; //-1 if not set
    int status; //0 if running, 1 if completed, 2 if stopped
    struct process* currProcess; //max of 2 with pipes
    struct process* secondProcess;
    char state; //'F' if forground or 'B' if background
    int twoProcess;
} job;

typedef struct process{
    char **instruction; //current instruction to be executed
    int *inputPipe;
    int *outputPipe;
    char *inputFile;
    char *outputFile;
    int status; //status
    int completed; //1 if completed
    char stopped; //1 if stopped
    pid_t pid; //pid of process
} process;

typedef struct job{
    char **instruction;
    struct job* nextJob; //next active
    pid_t pgid; //-1 if not set
    int status; //0 if running, 1 if completed, 2 if stopped
    struct process* currProcess; //max of 2 with pipes
    struct process* secondProcess;
    char state; //'F' if forground or 'B' if background
    int twoProcess;
} job;
```

Somehow valgrind indicates that tempP and currProcess are not getting free. However since I reference those pointers by creating a job I do eventually free the values using the free_job method. If i try to add free(tempP) or free (currinstruction) I get a segfault. Any help would be really appreciated. I've been trying different things for hours.

On a side notes for a concept based, if I have:

```
char **input;
char **sample = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 30);
input = sample; 
free(input)
```

Do I also have to free sample?

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to say anything based on the information you provide. Try to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added a sample small question which is a concept I'm unclear about

Comment: Regarding your side example, you free allocated memory, not pointers. One call to `malloc` must have exactly one matching call to `free`.

Comment: each call to a member of the malloc family should be immediately followed by check that the returned pointer is not NULL.

Comment: given your 'side sample' each malloc needs to be free'd only once.  However, since both input and sample contain the same pointer value, neither variable will point to anything useful after the call to free.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is unclear, for instance, in your side example you seems to allocate an array of char of 30 characters. To do this, you don't need to do a pointer of pointer, this is enough:

```
char *input;
char *sample = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 30);
input = sample; 
free(input)
```

And you don't need to free sample, but sample will be invalied when you will free input, because they reference the same allocated block. So don't try to reuse sample after the 'free(input)'